# How to lazy load images and make them available for print

Tags: javascript, html, image, printing, lazy-loading

Some websites have lots of images, so **lazyloading** seems appropiate to reduce load times and data consumption. But what if you also need to support **printing** for that website?

I mean, you *can* try to detect the print event and then load the images, with something like this:

### HTML

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
```

*Note:* this is a one by one pixels gif dummy image.

### JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  img = document.querySelector('img');
  var isPrinting = window.matchMedia('print');
  isPrinting.addListener((media) => {
    if (media.matches) {
      img.src = 'http://unsplash.it/500/300/?image=705';
    }
  })
});
```

*Note:* if you try this in a code playground, remove the `DOMContentLoaded` event (or simply fork these: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/31yLp41p/) | [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmQgZq)).

*Note:* I didn't event bother with the `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` for [**obvious reasons**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=beforeafterprint).

This will work fine if the image is cached, but then again that's precisely **not** the point. The image/s should all load and then appear in the printing screen.

Do you have any ideas? Has anyone successfully implemented a **print-ready** lazyloading plugin?

### Update

I've tried **redirecting** the user after the print dialog is detected, to a flagged version of the website a.k.a `website.com?print=true` where lazyloading is deactivated and all images load normally.

This method is improved by applying the `window.print()` method in this flagged print-ready version of the page, opening a new print dialog once all images are finished loading, and showing a *"wait for it"* message in the meantime at the top of the page.

*Important note:* this method was tested in Chrome, it does not work in Firefox nor Edge (hence why this is not an answer, but a testimony).

It works in Chrome beacuse the print dialog closes when you redirect to another website (in this case same url but flagged). In Edge and Firefox the print dialog is an actual window and it does not close it, making it pretty unusable.

Comment: have u tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147907/jquery-lazyload-to-work-with-printing

Comment: Hey! Can you please clarify the question? What exactly are you looking for? Lazy load images when user is about to print? Can you demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @WearyAdventurer I'm looking for a way to load all images that weren't loaded because they're are waiting to be lazyload, as soon as the user opens the print dialog. The issue is demonstrated in any of the code playgrounds I have made available, just hit Ctrl + P with an empty cache.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Yes.

Comment: That's a clever solution in your update; with your update, are you saying you're not able to call `window.print()` in Firefox nor Edge? Or unable to redirect? Or something else? Apologies, it's probably straight forward, I need some coffee!

Comment: @ArthurWeborg the original print dialog does not close in Firefox nor Edge, therefore you would end up with two print dialogs which makes for a very confusing user experience and makes it unviable in a production scenario.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on your desired functionality, I'm not quite sure what you want to do is feasible. As a developer we don't really have control over a users browser. Here are my thoughts as to why this isn't fully possible.

1. Hooking the event to go and load your missing images won't let you guarantee images will make it from the server into your page. More specifically, the PDF generated for your print preview is going to get generated before your image(s) is done loading, the `img.src = "..."` is asynchronous. You'd run into similar issues with `onbeforeprint` as well, unfortunately. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not (example, your fiddle worked when testing in safari, but did not in Chrome)
2. You cannot [stall or stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6647392/1992129) the  print call -- you can't force the browser to wait for your image to finish loading in the lazy loading context. (I read something about using alerts to achieve this once, but it seemed really hacky to me, was more of a deterrent to printing than stalling)
3. You cannot force `img.src` to get that data synchronously in a lazy-load context. There are some methods of doing this, but they are [clever hacks -- referenced as pure evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19973880/1992129) and may not work in always. I found [another link with a similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131778/1992129)

So we have a problem, if the images are not loaded by the time print event is fired, we cannot force the browser to wait until they are done. Sure, we can hook and go get those images on print, but as above points out, we cannot wait for those resources to load before the print preview pops up.

#### Potential solution (inspired by links in point three as well as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048852/1992129))

You could almost get away with doing a synchronous XMLHttpRequest. Syncrhonous XMLHTTPRequests will not let you change the responseType, they are always strings. However, you could convert the string value to an arrayBuffer encode it to a base-64 encoded string, and set the src to a dataURL (see the link that referenced clever hacks) -- however, when I tried this I got an error in [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31yLp41p/2/) -- so it would be possible, if things were configured correctly, in theory. I'm hesitant to say yes you can, since I wasn't able to get the fiddle working with the following (but it's a route you could explore!).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://unsplash.it/500/300/?image=705",false);
xhr.send(null);
if (request.status === 200) {
    //we cannot change the resposne type in synchronous XMLHTTPRequests
    //we can convert the string into a dataURL though
    var arr = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    // Convert the int array to a binary string
    // We have to use apply() as we are converting an *array*
    // and String.fromCharCode() takes one or more single values, not
    // an array.
    var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,arr);

    // This is supported in modern browsers
    var b64=btoa(raw);
    var dataURL="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+b64;
    img.src = dataURL;
}
```

#### Work around to enhance the user experience

Something you could do is have some text that only displays in the print version of your page (via `@print` css media) that says "images are still loading, cancel your print request and try again" and when the images are finished loading, remove that "still waiting on resources try again message" from the DOM. Farther, you could wrap your main content inside an element that inverses the display to none when content is not loaded, so all you see is that message in the print preview dialog.

Going off of the code you posted this could look something like the following (see updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31yLp41p/1/)):

**CSS**

```
.printing-not-ready-message{
  display:none;
}
@media print{
  .printing-not-ready-message{
    display:block;
  }
  .do-not-print-content{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="printing-not-ready-message">
Images are still loading please cancel your preview and try again shortly.
</div>
<div class="do-not-print-content">
    <h1>Welcome to my Lazy Page</h1>
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
    <p>Insert some comment about picture</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  img = document.querySelector('img');
  var isPrinting = window.matchMedia('print');
  isPrinting.addListener((media) => {
    if (media.matches) {
      img.src = 'http://unsplash.it/500/300/?image=705';
      //depending on how the lazy loading is done, the following might
      //exist in some other call, should happen after all images are loaded.
      //There is only 1 image in this example so this code can be called here.
      img.onload = ()=>{
          document.querySelector(".printing-not-ready-message").remove();
          document.querySelector(".do-not-print-content").className=""
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Very complete answer, if nobody else comes up with something, you'll have the bounty. In any case, +1.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great question, have been thinking about nonstop since I first saw it. I got to thinking more about my point 3, I think it might be worth exploring, but I think jsFiddle was preventing the code from working (potentially a configuration on their end, or that of unsplash.it that stopped it from working). I updated my answer, the js in that is supported in modern browsers. If I find some more free time I'll play around with it some more!

Comment: Interested to see if someone does think of something else! It's a neat problem to solve.

Comment: Well, blocking the main thread with a synchronous http request is being deprecated, but maybe I can come up with something similar.

Comment: That's a good point too, forgot that synchronous was being deprecated.

Comment: Check out the updated question if you care to see my attempts on solving this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of the [vanilla-lazyload](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload) script and I've recently developed a feature that makes print of all images possible!

Tested cross browser using [this repo code](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload-print-test) which is [live here](https://www.andreaverlicchi.eu/lazyload-print-test/).

Take a look and let me know what you think!
I'm open to pull requests on GitHub of course.

Comment: I use your project everywhere! I'll try it out as soon as I can. When I was working on this issue the onbeforeprint event wasn't an option, but then again you do use matchMedia for Safari, so, I guess my question is, how did you get it to load all images before the print snapshot is taken.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in FireFox.  No images show in my print.

Comment: This is also broken on Chrome as of today and it requires to create a print button.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a lazy loading jquery plugin that supports showing images on print using the window.onbeforeprint events and mediaQueryListeners.
https://github.com/msigley/Unveil-EX/

Answer (score 1):

```
//declare custom onbeforeprint method
const customOnBeforePrint = () => {
    const smoothScroll = (h) => {
        let i = h || 0;
        if (i < 200) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollY, window.scrollY + i);
                smoothScroll(i + 10);
            }, 10);
        }
    };

    let height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    let newHeight;
    while (true) {
        smoothScroll(100);

        if (newHeight === height) break;
        height = newHeight;
    }
};

//override the onbeforeprint method
window.onbeforeprint = customOnBeforePrint;
```

Copy&Paste that block into devtool's console and then try to click print button. That workaround is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is in the same boat as I was: when using the browser native `loading="lazy"`, you can simply remove that attribute when printing is going to happen. Below is my jQuery implementation.

```
window.onbeforeprint = function () {
  $('img').each(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('loading')
  });
}
```

Chrome will then just load all images and they will show up when printing.