# Loading="lazy" HTML attribute: How to load the images not yet loaded when user asks for a print?

Tags: html, image, lazy-loading, loading

I found this problem this morning. I load all images on my page as 'lazy' (with the loading=lazy attribute), but when I request a print without having scrolled down, all those images that are not yet loaded (because I didn't scroll to it yet) are not loaded for the print.

So is there a way to keep the lazy, but force load those images when someone is trying to print the page?

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68652615/616443?

Comment: Oh well that answer is really on the wrong question. Question is asking about a JS lazyloader. But I'll try that out.